# LASSO REGRESSION and categorical variables

Tags: lasso

Coefficients:

```
(Intercept) 0.2991246444
animalDog -0.0006095736
mfMale .
age -0.0357061834
in.month2 .
in.month3 .
in.month4 .
in.month5 .
in.month6 .
in.month7 .
in.month8 .
in.month9 .
in.month10 .
in.month11 .
in.month12 .
in.reasonPublicAssist -0.1980702921 
in.reasonStray .
in.intact1 .
```

In this LASSO coefficient estimates, `in.reasonStray` is being merged with the base level.

`in.reason` and `in.month` are both categorical variables with 3 levels and 12 levels. So, one level is chosen to be the base level. But, `in.reasonStray` is merged with the base level.

So, it may be hard to interpret the base level if so many levels are merged.

But, what about the `in.month` variable? The coefficients for every level are 0, so does that mean every level is being merged with the base level as well? or is that categorical variable dropped because all of the dummy variables are dropped?

Comment: Why are you trying to interpret these coefficients?  What is the question you're trying to answer?

Comment: I am just trying to answer my own question. I know that in.reasonStray merges with the reference level but I am wondering if Lasso will remove in.month categorical variable since in.month dummy variables' beta are technically are 0. For a numerical variable, if that variable's coefficient is 0, LASSO removes that variable. Just wondering if that rule applies to categorical variable if 11 month levels are 0.

Comment: You say "`in.reason` and `in.month` are both categorical variables with 3 levels and 12 levels" but in fact you have 2 and 11 variables respectively presumably each with 2 levels.  If you are using LASSO, better to have 3 and 12 so you do not have a distorting  arbitrary choice of base, and let LASSO find which ones are best for base (with LASSO, multicollinearity is less of an issue).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writing out the linear model explicitly can help answer interpretation questions: in this case your whole model is

$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot  I(\textrm{animal}=\textrm{dog}) + \beta_2 \cdot \textrm{age} + \beta_3 \cdot I(\textrm{reason} = \textrm{PublicAssist})
$$
where $I()$ is an *indicator function*, i.e. $I(.) = 1$ if the condition is true and 0 if it is false.

So for (e.g.) a non-dog animal of age 0, the predicted value is $\beta_0 + \beta_1$ if $\textrm{reason}$ is $\textrm{PublicAssist}$, otherwise it's $\beta_0$ (this is equivalent to your statement that "`in.reasonStray` is merged with the base level"). Since `month` doesn't appear in the equation at all, you can see that that's equivalent to dropping `month` entirely (i.e., all months are equivalent for prediction purposes).

You appear to be using *treatment contrasts* (the default in model construction in R). Since you're doing lasso regression you could use *one-hot encoding* instead (which creates a dummy/indicator variable for *every* level of a categorical variable, not just every  level other than the first/baseline level); that might make interpretation easier. (R doesn't use one-hot encoding because it induces multicollinearity if there is more than one categorical predictor; multicollinearity causes problems for ordinary, non-penalized versions of regression.)

Comment: thank you! That clearly helps! I was pretty sure since month coefficients are gone after LASSO, we will technically drop the **month** variable. It's like in the original model, let's say we have a numerical variable but after the LASSO, its coefficient estimate is 0. Then, we drop that variable as well.

Comment: As far as I can understand your question, yes.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. You clearly helped me out!